# Rollback is working on a transaction but crashes anyway by SQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on a cinema ticketing java application.
There is a grid of chairs, the user selects all chairs to book, then press ok to book it (insert rows in a mysql database). If any of the bookings pretended to do fails due to duplicate entries, all of them are rollbacked.
To do it, listening button "buy" I do:

```
    case "buy":         
        try {
        boolean success = true;         
            for(Booking b : bookingsToDo) {
                 if(DbConnect.getConnection().getAutoCommit())
                     DbConnect.getConnection().setAutoCommit(false);

                        success = controllerBooking.insertBooking(b);

                if(!success) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frameMain, "Error occurred, booking failed");

                    DbConnect.getConnection().rollback();                                               
                } 
            }

            if(success) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frameMain, "Booking done");

                DbConnect.getConnection().commit();

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        break;
```

This is working, because actually all the bookings are being reversed.
But anyway is throwing: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:

> Can't call rollback when autocommit=true

so the program fails then.
How is it possible that rollback is working and at the same time throwing a "Can't rollback" message? And how could it be when I'm doing setAutoCommit(false) in every loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbConnect.getConnection()` is getting a new connection each time its called.

Autocommit is set on a per connection basis. Therefore you are rolling back on a different connection. The controllerBooking also needs a connection reference to use the same connection.

So:

```
        con = DbConnect.getConnection(); 
        con.setAutoCommit(false);

        for(Booking b : bookingsToDo) {
            success = controllerBooking.insertBooking(con, b);

            if(!success) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frameMain, "Error occurred, booking failed");

                con.rollback();                                               
                break;
            } 
        }
        con.commit();
```